# Filter duplicate options from select using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Question:** I got 2 option name ***try*** and ***restrock*** , when i at ***try*** option add **macbook pro** to the assigned box , after that, i go to the ***restock*** option to add the same product call **macbook pro**, then the system will allow user to add again. So that, how can i check it when ***try*** option aldready got **macbook pro** then when user try to add again in ***restock*** option system will auto remove the **mac book pro** from ***try*** option and add new **macbook pro** to the ***restock*** option???

[image: fdsadsa]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code that I write

```
function addSelectedProducts(row_lab) {
    $('#product_placeholder'+row_lab+' :selected').each(function() {

        $(this).remove();

        $('#related'+row_lab+' option[value=\'' + $(this).attr('value') + '\']').remove();

        $('#related'+row_lab).append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');

        $('#product_added input[value=\'' + $(this).attr('value') + '\']').remove();

        var featured_string = document.getElementById('imploding_feature'+row_lab).value;

        var sear_exist = featured_string.search('/'+$(this).attr('value')+'/');
        if(sear_exist == -1){
            featured_string = featured_string + $(this).attr('value') + ',';
            featured_string = featured_string.replace(/^,/, '');
            $('#imploding_feature'+row_lab).val(featured_string);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: share the code that you have tried

Comment: i already post the code